# Is it undefined behaviour in C to use pointer to a typedef type as a pointer to the primitive type?

Tags: c, pointers, typedef, undefined-behavior

Suppose that one has the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int myIntType;

int main()
{
    int a;
    myIntType *ptr = &a;

    *ptr = 1;

    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Does this invoke undefined behaviour?

Under any reasonable interpretation, I expect this should simply set the value of `a` to `1` and therefore print the line `1` on `stdout`.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c -o main` on Mac OS X does not produce any errors or warnings, and produces the expected output on execution.

My question is purely theoretical, and I do not intend to use such a construct in real-life code.

Comment: It is not, what would prompt the assertion?

Comment: why should there be an undefined behaviour?

Comment: I was thinking about whether the compiler could somehow make a `myIntType *` of a different size than an `int *`, or perhaps consider them as incompatible similarly to the case where one tries to cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer to a struct containing the same initial fields (referring to the strict-aliasing issue).

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.7.8 Type definitions 3 [...] A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a
synonym for the type so specified.*

Comment: Note that while the standard allows this, static code analysis tools such as LINT will barf out pages of warnings about this, since the `typedef` could potentially change in the future.

Comment: @TobErnack:  Pointers are always the same size.  `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(struct s*) == sizeof(void*)` always, with the exception of the almost defunct 16 bits apps, where far pointers did not have the same size as near pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) about the typedef specifier:

> The typedef specifier ... may declare array and function types, pointers and references, class types, etc. Every identifier introduced in this declaration becomes a typedef-name, *which is a synonym for the type* of the object or function that it would become if the keyword typedef were removed.

In other words, it is the exact same as if you removed your custom type and replaced it with `int`. Thus, it is well-defined behavior. `int` and `myIntType` are 100% interchangeable.

That is actually a c++ reference. From K&R, chapter 6.7 on `typedef`:

> C provides a facility called `typedef` for creating new data type names. For example, the declaration `typedef int Length;` makes the name `Length` a synonym for `int`. The type `Length` can be used in declarations, casts, etc., in exactly the same ways that the type `int` can be.

Do be aware that K&R isn't the most up-to-date standard. The other answer cites the current standard. As far as I know, `typedef` hasn't changed.

Comment: It also says, "The typedef-names are aliases for existing types, and are not declarations of new types." This language might be a little clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `myIntType *` is the same as `int *`.

Section 6.7.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives an example of this:

> *4* EXAMPLE 1 After
>
> ```
> typedef int MILES, KLICKSP();
> typedef struct { double hi, lo; } range;
> ```
>
> the constructions
>
> ```
> MILES distance;
> extern KLICKSP *metricp;
> range x;
> range z, *zp;
> ```
>
> are all valid declarations. **The type of `distance` is `int`**, that of
>   `metricp` is "pointer to function with no parameter specification
>   returning `int`", and that of `x` and `z` is the specified structure; `zp` is
>   a pointer to such a structure. **The object `distance` has a type
>   compatible with any other `int` object.**